# Python. Получение значения из словаря

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, словари

```
    {
"response": {
"items": [{
"member_id": 489569031,
"join_date": 1544905304,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_owner": true,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": 344648652,
"join_date": 1531169722,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 381682064,
"join_date": 1532985294,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 419089414,
"join_date": 1535742950,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 287329435,
"join_date": 1536594760,
"invited_by": 198805760,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 217899126,
"join_date": 1536941326,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 465182958,
"join_date": 1537046652,
"invited_by": 86424744,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 500599465,
"join_date": 1538339905,
"invited_by": 399364630,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 409024435,
"join_date": 1539865633,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": -158645511,
"join_date": 1541260188,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": -164919759,
"join_date": 1541316613,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 311390634,
"join_date": 1541417307,
"invited_by": 86424744,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 228035883,
"join_date": 1541694910,
"invited_by": 86424744,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 221931093,
"join_date": 1541770108,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 313737714,
"join_date": 1541777175,
"invited_by": 274084524,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 257019930,
"join_date": 1541890222,
"invited_by": 393022853,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 445802546,
"join_date": 1541939915,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 464663057,
"join_date": 1542035043,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 516646415,
"join_date": 1542086847,
"invited_by": 471719269,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": -170393012,
"join_date": 1542115788,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": 385151846,
"join_date": 1542117016,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 264428385,
"join_date": 1542117016,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 477782687,
"join_date": 1542118822,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 297341004,
"join_date": 1542119912,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 241623849,
"join_date": 1542120566,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 477668427,
"join_date": 1542178001,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 336105345,
"join_date": 1542178658,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 354433435,
"join_date": 1542265306,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 225029234,
"join_date": 1542267798,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 175847569,
"join_date": 1542275877,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 222069293,
"join_date": 1542298180,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 472230765,
"join_date": 1542532303,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 442398334,
"join_date": 1543002679,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 518841423,
"join_date": 1543409271,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 393022853,
"join_date": 1544204017,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 509255053,
"join_date": 1544346308,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 516302950,
"join_date": 1544348850,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 282764885,
"join_date": 1544459590,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 317455062,
"join_date": 1544459590,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 521124632,
"join_date": 1544628159,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 451593529,
"join_date": 1544803703,
"invited_by": 445837958,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 323934047,
"join_date": 1544849876,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 515067665,
"join_date": 1544852327,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 435500129,
"join_date": 1544889496,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 419314962,
"join_date": 1544893131,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": -153955265,
"join_date": 1544900236,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": 512013967,
"join_date": 1545035258,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 259950884,
"join_date": 1545035258,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 470347743,
"join_date": 1545052973,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 522013902,
"join_date": 1545233726,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 297765047,
"join_date": 1545271520,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 333965337,
"join_date": 1545485316,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 399364630,
"join_date": 1545505542,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 281499908,
"join_date": 1545565304,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 405738595,
"join_date": 1545654689,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 430239264,
"join_date": 1545668435,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 347117260,
"join_date": 1545751966,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 247767981,
"join_date": 1545819914,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 380168421,
"join_date": 1545980788,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 192683201,
"join_date": 1546005285,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 360583103,
"join_date": 1546020152,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 262541003,
"join_date": 1546076963,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 338165202,
"join_date": 1546089652,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 395259174,
"join_date": 1546196614,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 177402368,
"join_date": 1546292748,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 453795933,
"join_date": 1546529265,
"invited_by": 279632309,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 409273019,
"join_date": 1546697905,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 373788989,
"join_date": 1546799624,
"invited_by": 475242078,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 263430103,
"join_date": 1546801381,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 513801035,
"join_date": 1546898914,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 355202437,
"join_date": 1547128482,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 500144925,
"join_date": 1547128482,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 198805760,
"join_date": 1547144100,
"invited_by": 404406475,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 514240571,
"join_date": 1547403933,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 221400876,
"join_date": 1547803664,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 505814050,
"join_date": 1548145245,
"invited_by": 324505394,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 442881387,
"join_date": 1548154259,
"invited_by": 505814050,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 254582621,
"join_date": 1549479193,
"invited_by": 217899126,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 404406475,
"join_date": 1550237369,
"invited_by": 86424744,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": -178999519,
"join_date": 1551361173,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": 530746886,
"join_date": 1551361590,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"is_admin": true
}, {
"member_id": 378213426,
"join_date": 1551373711,
"invited_by": 341911892,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 438622646,
"join_date": 1551374960,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 519010947,
"join_date": 1551375291,
"invited_by": 489569031,
"can_kick": true
}, {
"member_id": 386990493,
"join_date": 1551383650,
"invited_by": 254582621,
"can_kick": true
}],
"count": 85,
"profiles": [{
"id": 86424744,
"first_name": "Танечка",
"last_name": "Чернова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 175847569,
"first_name": "Лена",
"last_name": "Филипченко",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 177402368,
"first_name": "Александра",
"last_name": "Богданова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 192683201,
"first_name": "Мария",
"last_name": "Чернякова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 198805760,
"first_name": "Мариам",
"last_name": "Булгадарян",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 217899126,
"first_name": "Святослав",
"last_name": "Беликов",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 221400876,
"first_name": "Angelina",
"last_name": "Maylik",
"deactivated": "banned"
}, {
"id": 221931093,
"first_name": "Лукерья",
"last_name": "Ландсберг",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 222069293,
"first_name": "Эля",
"last_name": "Биктимирова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 225029234,
"first_name": "Елизавета",
"last_name": "Емельянова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 228035883,
"first_name": "Даша",
"last_name": "Лубская",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 241623849,
"first_name": "Екатерина",
"last_name": "Миглан",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 247767981,
"first_name": "Юлия",
"last_name": "Александрова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 254582621,
"first_name": "Настя",
"last_name": "Склокина",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 257019930,
"first_name": "Роман",
"last_name": "Саглаев",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 259950884,
"first_name": "Лидия",
"last_name": "Никитина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 262541003,
"first_name": "Евгения",
"last_name": "Разунаева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 263430103,
"first_name": "Алина",
"last_name": "Андреева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 264428385,
"first_name": "Ангелина",
"last_name": "Дмитриева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 274084524,
"first_name": "Инга",
"last_name": "Золотых",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 279632309,
"first_name": "Ксения",
"last_name": "Майская",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 281499908,
"first_name": "Ксения",
"last_name": "Иванова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 282764885,
"first_name": "Карина",
"last_name": "Соколова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 287329435,
"first_name": "Валерия",
"last_name": "Кирейкина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 297341004,
"first_name": "Валерия",
"last_name": "Темникова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 297765047,
"first_name": "Катя",
"last_name": "Демьянова",
"deactivated": "deleted"
}, {
"id": 311390634,
"first_name": "Александра",
"last_name": "Любимова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 313737714,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Ершова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 317455062,
"first_name": "Зайнаб",
"last_name": "Мирова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 323934047,
"first_name": "Полина",
"last_name": "Данцева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 324505394,
"first_name": "Катюша",
"last_name": "Строкова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 333965337,
"first_name": "Вилена",
"last_name": "Харитонова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 336105345,
"first_name": "Ксения",
"last_name": "Богатикова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 338165202,
"first_name": "Ксения",
"last_name": "Данилова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 341911892,
"first_name": "Александр",
"last_name": "Измайлов",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 344648652,
"first_name": "Маша",
"last_name": "Барковская",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 347117260,
"first_name": "Юля",
"last_name": "Щепёткина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 354433435,
"first_name": "Лия",
"last_name": "Соловей",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 355202437,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Хоменко",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 360583103,
"first_name": "Мирей",
"last_name": "Кабулова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 373788989,
"first_name": "Инна",
"last_name": "Иванова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 378213426,
"first_name": "Софа",
"last_name": "Девина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 380168421,
"first_name": "Фаина",
"last_name": "Тимохина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 381682064,
"first_name": "Ностя",
"last_name": "Литовченко",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 385151846,
"first_name": "Полина",
"last_name": "Андерсон",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 386990493,
"first_name": "Виктория",
"last_name": "Карасик",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 393022853,
"first_name": "Ева",
"last_name": "Гельтман",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 395259174,
"first_name": "Алина",
"last_name": "Исакович",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 399364630,
"first_name": "Амина",
"last_name": "Белка",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 404406475,
"first_name": "Данил",
"last_name": "Лис",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 405738595,
"first_name": "Агата",
"last_name": "Шнайдер",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 409024435,
"first_name": "Варвара",
"last_name": "Небесная",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 409273019,
"first_name": "Александра",
"last_name": "Чистякова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 419089414,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Ступина",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 419314962,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Насибулина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 430239264,
"first_name": "Александра",
"last_name": "Кошкина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 435500129,
"first_name": "Елизавета",
"last_name": "Шевцова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 438622646,
"first_name": "Дарья",
"last_name": "Булка",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 442398334,
"first_name": "Юля",
"last_name": "Мечникова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 442881387,
"first_name": "Mr",
"last_name": "Barmaley",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 445802546,
"first_name": "Денис",
"last_name": "Яббаров",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 445837958,
"first_name": "Ангелина",
"last_name": "Сверинова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 451593529,
"first_name": "Ева",
"last_name": "Абрамова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 453795933,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Малиновская",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 464663057,
"first_name": "Кристина",
"last_name": "Савченко",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 465182958,
"first_name": "Даша",
"last_name": "Воробьева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 470347743,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Щёголева",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 471719269,
"first_name": "Нелли",
"last_name": "Хххххххх",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 472230765,
"first_name": "Анастасия",
"last_name": "Андронова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 475242078,
"first_name": "Татьяна",
"last_name": "Самуйлова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 477668427,
"first_name": "Юлия",
"last_name": "Бондарь",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 477782687,
"first_name": "Алексей",
"last_name": "Тронев",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 489569031,
"first_name": "Павел",
"last_name": "Чёрный",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 500144925,
"first_name": "Zhanel",
"last_name": "Ospanova",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 500599465,
"first_name": "No",
"last_name": "Name",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 505814050,
"first_name": "Богдан",
"last_name": "Король",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 509255053,
"first_name": "Женя",
"last_name": "Кирова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 512013967,
"first_name": "Ксения",
"last_name": "Евсеева",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 513801035,
"first_name": "Yulia",
"last_name": "Yachislava",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 514240571,
"first_name": "Karina",
"last_name": "Alieva",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 515067665,
"first_name": "Динара",
"last_name": "Миласс",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 516302950,
"first_name": "Лера",
"last_name": "Тимурова",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 516646415,
"first_name": "Ишемия",
"last_name": "Итиносе",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 518841423,
"first_name": "Елизавета",
"last_name": "Карнелина",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 519010947,
"first_name": "Анатолий",
"last_name": "Плотников",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 521124632,
"first_name": "Карина",
"last_name": "Филипова",
"is_closed": true,
"can_access_closed": false
}, {
"id": 522013902,
"first_name": "Олеся",
"last_name": "Покровская",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}, {
"id": 530746886,
"first_name": "West",
"last_name": "Side",
"is_closed": false,
"can_access_closed": true
}],
"groups": [{
"id": 153955265,
"name": "Чат-менеджер",
"screen_name": "cm",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 0,
"is_member": 0,
"is_advertiser": 0,
"photo_50": "htt=19.u...SOz083NH8.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_100": "htt=8.us...kv6mXxcy8.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "htt=AOMBTEtd4.jpg?ava=1"
}, {
"id": 158645511,
"name": "Мия Лютая",
"screen_name": "miyabot",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 0,
"is_member": 0,
"is_advertiser": 0,
"photo_50": "ht=5.u...mb7zT89ts.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_100": "htt=-9.us...Fks2Q7J1E.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "htt=r_Eo58.jpg?ava=1"
}, {
"id": 164919759,
"name": "Бот для перевода голосовых сообщений в текст",
"screen_name": "vkvoicebot",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "page",
"is_admin": 0,
"is_member": 0,
"is_advertiser": 0,
"photo_50": "https://sun1-13.u...zgXM7yVfk.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_100": "https://sun1-2.us...ELQuVLaXY.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "https://sun1-11.u...H0y-NPnYs.jpg?ava=1"
}, {
"id": 170393012,
"name": "Кай",
"screen_name": "manager_kai",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 0,
"is_member": 0,
"is_advertiser": 0,
"photo_50": "htt=...AKr_Lf6GM.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_100": "ht=..QmHBg6ao8.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "ht=s=UPeZI.jpg?ava=1"
}, {
"id": 178999519,
"name": "Meow Manager",
"screen_name": "club178999519",
"is_closed": 0,
"type": "group",
"is_admin": 1,
"admin_level": 3,
"is_member": 1,
"is_advertiser": 1,
"photo_50": "http=.us...gGIBf-jzc==1",
"photo_100": "h=.us...280i6H16M.jpg?ava=1",
"photo_200": "h=Qf836rNE.jpg?ava=1"
}]
}
}
```

Я имею код такого вида, из него мне надо выудить фамилии людей, то есть last_name параметр, я пробовал: `last_names = [i.get('last_name') for i in ju.get('response', {}).get('profiles')]` Но это возвращает: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе ваших JSON данных (допустим переменная называется `ju_json`):

```
import json

ju = json.loads(ju_json)

for profile in ju['response']['profiles']:
    print(profile['last_name'])
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90457/discussion-on-answer-by-andrey-python----).

Answer (score 1):

Поле last_name находится во вложенном словаре, в списке profiles.
Если Вам нужно получить список фамилий, делайте так:

```
last_names = [i.get('last_name') for i in ju.get('response', {}).get('profiles')]
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Поправил. Не items, а profiles.

Comment: last_names = [i.get('last_name') for i in ju.get('response', {}).get('profiles')]

>>>>>>>
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not iterable


Питон не сдаётся

Comment: В словаре, который вы используете, видимо нет ключа response, потому вместо profiles приходит None.

Comment: подредактировал код, теперь он один в один

Comment: true - таких литералов в питоне нету.
Вы его, как понял, из джейсона дисереализовали?

Comment: да, json штука.

Comment: Сделайте json.loads() это приведёт джейсон к виду питоновского словаря. Потом уже доставайте оттуда всё, что нужно.